# Power BI On-Premises Data Gateway hosted in an AWS EC2 instance

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, powerbi, data-gateway

I've been working with Power BI for quite a long time now and everytime I needed to use a data gateway, I used the one installed in my personal computer.

But recently I was asked to host the on-premises Data Gateway in a VM, so I was wondering: **is it possible to install and configure an on-premises Data Gateway in a AWS EC2 instance?** If so, how should I do it?

I also considered using an AWS Workspace, but considering the prices, I'd rather use an EC2.

Comment: It has been in quite a while when you asked this question. I am just reaching out to see, did you get to a solution?

Answer (score 1):

Simple answer, Yes, long answer, why would you want to?

The Power BI on-premises data gateway is designed to be installed on Windows machine, as the requirements are below.

- .NET Framework 4.6 (Gateway release August 2019 and earlier)
- .NET Framework 4.7.2 (Gateway release September 2019 and later)
- A 64-bit version of Windows 8 or a 64-bit version of Windows Server
  2012 R2

So you would have to host a windows VM in your AWS environment to use it, which is not rally a cost effect way.

The on-premises data gateway, without getting into the detail, works abit like vpn and creates a tunnel to Power BI for the data to be transmitted. It works over Https so companies with existing infrastructure big or small can hook up existing databases and systems without needing to worry about, firewalls, ports, security, ip addresses, etc.

If have data in AWS or even if you wanted to connect through AWS to on premises data, I would definitely looking at other options. You have the full power of the AWS security infrastructure at your fingers tips.

Power BI can connect directly to RDS and many other services hosted on AWS, so I would be thinking about what my data source is first and the best way to connect it.

Comment: Hi @RickWeb, I am going over this article https://docs.aws.amazon.com/whitepapers/latest/using-power-bi-with-aws-cloud/connecting-the-microsoft-power-bi-service-to-aws-data-sources.html. To complement your comment, I think the gateway is the right option if the PowerBI service is in Azure but your data is in AWS. What do you think?